# Mogoose findOneAndUpdate how to know wether object exist and if modified

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using `findOneAndUpdate` method of mongoose:

```
function update_one_record(Model, unique_constraint, new_updated_values){ 
    obj=Model.findOneAndUpdate(
        //Similarly we have findOneAndRemove
        unique_constraint, 
        {$set: new_updated_values},
        {upsert: true}, 
        function(err, raw){
            console.log(err, raw)
    })
    return obj
}
```

I want to know:

1. if that object existed or not
2. if  object modified or not if not what is the errors.

Comment: For the second doubt you can check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558418/what-parameters-are-passed-to-mongoose-callbacks/43555659#43555659

Answer (score 4):

From the mongoose [findOneAndUpdate docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate):

> **Model.findOneAndUpdate([conditions], [update], [options], [callback])**
>
> Issues a mongodb findAndModify update command.
>
> Finds a matching document, updates it according to the update arg,
>   passing any options, and returns the found document (if any) to the
>   callback. The query executes immediately if callback is passed.

As for your questions:

1. If a document is found it will be passed to the callback as a parameter. You can use the option `new: true` to return the modified document rather than the original, which defaults to true.
2. The errors, if any, will be passed to the callback function as well.

It is important to note that findOneAndUpdate will NOT trigger any of the following:

- defaults
- setters
- validators
- middleware