# Mongoose: how to check if document is modified via model.findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

In mongoose, we can check if an update operation has modified the document with `model.update()`:

```
model.update(query, update, function(err, raw){
    if (raw.nModified >= 1) console.log('document is modified!')
});
```

Is there a way to do the same with `model.findOneAndUpdate()`?

```
model.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, { new: true }, function(err, doc){
    if (doc) {
        // So MongoDB found the document, but is there a way 
        // to know the document was indeed modified?
    }
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mogoose findOneAndUpdate how to know wether object exist and if modified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29063205/mogoose-findoneandupdate-how-to-know-wether-object-exist-and-if-modified)

Comment: There is another option `upsert: bool - creates the object if it doesn't exist. defaults to false.`
So if its false, and mongodb found the document, doc in the callback function is always the modified document

Comment: You can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558418/what-parameters-are-passed-to-mongoose-callbacks/43555659#43555659)

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the option `{ passRawResult : true }` to mongoose to advice mongoose to pass the raw result of the underlying mongodb driver, in this case mongodb-native, as a third argument to the callback.

mongodb-native documentation for [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate)

```
model.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, { new: true, passRawResult : true }, function(err, doc, res){
    // res will look like
    // { value: { _id: 56a9fc80a7f9a4d41c344852, name: 'hugo updated', __v: 0 },
    //   lastErrorObject: { updatedExisting: true, n: 1 },
    //   ok: 1 }
});
```

In case the update did not succeed due to no matching document was found a `null` res will be passed to the callback. In case a document matched but field values where the same as before the update res object will not give you enough information to figure out if values were updated for the matching document.

Comment: This is parially true as it will at least report if something was matched effectively. But if you send exactly the same update ( or anything else that attempts to set a field to the value it already has ) then this will still report the document as "updated", even though nothing was acutally changed. This is because this method is still using the legacy API, and prior to the introducion of the Bulk API ( which modern API implementations use  ) there was no such acurate reporting of whether this was a modificaion or not. But kudos for mentioning the undocumented option.